# Datanode is running fine but not mentioned in live data nodes

Tags: hadoop, ssh

I have deployed `hadoop-3.0.0-alpha2` cluster on `ubuntu 15.10`. The details are:

1. There are 1 `namenode`(master) and 2 `datanodes`(slave1 & slave2) are running.
2. I am able to login to slaves from master by '`ssh slave1`' and master from slaves by '`ssh master`'.

The daemons are working fine I can see them by jps. But datanodes are not showing in livenodes of namenode webUI.

I have checked all configurations of my xml files and they are correct. Still livenodes are 0. My namenode and datanodes logs showing something like this.

Namenode log:

[image]

Datanode log:

[image]

Core-site.xml:

```
    fs.defaultFS
    hdfs://master:9000
```

hdfs-site.xml:

at Datanode:

```
    dfs.replication
    1

    dfs.datanode.data.dir
    file:/usr/local/hadoop_tmp/hdfs/datanode
```

at Namenode:

```
    dfs.namenode.name.dir
    file:/usr/local/hadoop_tmp/hdfs/namenode
```

mapred-site.xml:

```
    mapreduce.jobhistory.webapp.address
    master:19888

    mapreduce.job.tracker
    master:54311

    mapreduce.framework.name
    yarn
```

yarn-site.xml:

```
    yarn.nodemanager.aux-services
    mapreduce_shuffle

    yarn.nodemanager.aux-services.mapreduce.shuffle.class
    org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ShuffleHandler

    yarn.log-aggregation-enable
    true

    yarn.resourcemanager.resource-tracker.address
    master:8025

    yarn.resourcemanager.scheduler.address
    master:8035

    yarn.resourcemanager.address
    master:8050
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: datanode log clearly says datanode cannot communicate with namenode. you will have to post your configuration files as well.

Comment: I have edited my question and posted configuration files specifications. I did my best to post the files because I am unable to post more images.

Comment: Don't post images. Copy and paste from the terminal

Comment: By the way, Apache Ambari makes it much easier to setup Hadoop cluster. (not sure if hadoop 3 is supported, though)

Comment: @A_J change the port in core-site to 9090. and let me know

Comment: @RameshMaharjan still the problem is same. I have checked the logs its showing same issue

Comment: are you still seeing port 9000  or the port changed to 9090 in your logs?

Comment: port changed to 9090.